# Ajax request with codeigniter forbidden

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to do an ajax request with jquery and codeigniter framework, but when I try to access to the server page, I have a forbidden access.

Here's my jquery code :

```
$('#btHello').click(function () {
    var name = $('#name').val();
        alert(name);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:'name='+ name,
            url:'<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/AjaxTest/ajaxtest',
            success: function(result, status){
                $('#result1').html(result);
            },

            error: function (result, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

The error alert just shows "Forbidden", nothing more.

Does anyone know what is the problem ?

Here's the controler :

```
class AjaxTest extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('home/head');
        $this->load->view('home/nav');
        $this->load->view('test/ajaxTest');
        $this->load->view('home/foot');
    }

    public function ajaxTest(){
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        echo 'Hello '.$name;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I know if it acceptss POST method ?

Comment: I guess this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478355/ajax-csrf-403-forbidden-codeigniter

Comment: can I see the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send

```
$this->security->get_csrf_token_name() : $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
```

with the request. hope it'll solve your problem

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url().'/admin/getNewLocations' ?>",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        func: 'getNewLocations',
        '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
    },
    success: function(data) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, codeigniter will warn forbidden, when csrf checking fails.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know anything related to CI. Cheers