# CSRF enabled throws 403 (forbidden) in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ajaxform, csrf-token

So I planned to implement CSRF in my website and set what's needed which I think I set correctly but still having issue with ajax submit form.

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_token_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

This is what I have in my config, where I set `$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;` to prevent the regeneration on every submission (based on this discussion [Ajax CSRF 403 forbidden codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478355/ajax-csrf-403-forbidden-codeigniter)).

And my form, instead of using html form tag, I use `form_open()` and `form_close()`.

**Ajax submit form :**

```
$('#formData').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        cache : false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'example.com.sg/login/verify',
        data: formData,
        success: function (res) {
            if(res.status == true){
                window.location.href = res.redirect;
            }
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err.responseText)
        }
    });
})
```

**PHP function**

```
public function verify(){
    $this->form_validation
        ->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email')
        ->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == true){
        // do email and password verification
        echo json_encode([ 'status' => true, 'redirect' => base_url('dashboard') ]);
    } else {
        $this->returnFormError($this->form_validation->error_array());
    }
}
```

If I change the ajax type to `get` it works but not `post`. If viewing the code from console, my form has this csrf token included in hidden input.

Comment: its a bit less information i think - take a look @your browsers console (in chrome its the network tab) - this post should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603561/how-can-i-debug-a-http-post-in-chrome - and analyze your data in the headers tab - if you dont see the csrf information there - something went wrong

Comment: @sintakonte sorry for the late reply. I have checked from console at network tab at header section and I can see the csrf information at there.

Answer (score 0):

// in config.php
 $config['encryption_key'] = 'some key';
update this first

Comment: The result is same. What is the use of this config?